# Test for Armor stand with certain armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command that tests for an armor stand that has a pumpkin on the head and wears a leather chestplate, leggings and boots but I can't find the right inventory slots. How can I do this?

Here is the very basic command that I am trying to use:

```
/testfor @e[type=Armor_Stand] {SelectedItemSlot:0-8,Inventory:[{Slot:0-8b,tag:{display:{Name:"Example"}}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use this:

```
/testfor @e[type=ArmorStand] {Equipment:[{id:hand item},{id:boots},{id:pants},{id:chest},{id:helmet}]}
```

If you don't want to test for a certain slot just leave the `{ }` of that slot empty.
Like `Equipment:[{},{id:boots},{id:pants},{id:chest},{id:helmet}]` for testing only for armor and no hand item.

Comment: so i used this command but it can't find the armor stand i think that it needs the number of the slot to test for the armor stand
 /testfor @e[type=ArmorStand] {Equipment:[{},{id:leather_boots},{id:leather_pants},{id:leather_chest},{id:pumpking}]}

Comment: It's pumpkin, not pumpking

Comment: still nothing i think there is something missing from the command

Comment: @Alex try the command without the pumpkin, that thing might not count as armor

Comment: still nothing but i need it to have the pumpking for the idea that i have so what else i can do to make it work?